# Solving disputes. Is there any tool available?

Tags: facebook

I'm about to code a little application that will query the Facebook Graph API about orders with status=disputed in order to either refund the money or settle it again, allowing the customer support people to manage disputes in an agile way.

I would like to know if I'm not reinventing the wheel here. An application that interacts with the credits API and manages orders would be extremely useful, and I find strange that it hasn't been done before.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, there is nothing to do with disputes. I made an app to handle these disputes but it will be very helful if facebook deploys a tool.

Comment: Can you share what you did?